# I tried unwind but it doesn't return anything

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm supposed to find the ISBN and title of books that were published in **2012**.

**I have seen similar questions on StackOverflow but I tried and it doesn't work as well**

Also, I tried $unwind for the subject as well as book and subject.book.ISBN and all of it return nothing.
The reason I'm using $unwind is that there are similar books and ISBN

my script :

```
db.Subject.aggregate([
    {"$project": {_id: 0, "subject.book.ISBN":1,"subject.book.bookTitle":1 }},
    {"$unwind": "$subject.book"},
    {"$match":{"subject.book.yearPub":2012}}    
]).pretty();
```

the result I got is nothing

```
> db.Subject.aggregate([
... {"$project": {_id: 0, "subject.book.ISBN":1,"subject.book.bookTitle":1 }},
... {"$unwind": "$subject.book"},
... {"$match":{"subject.book.yearPub":2012}}
... ]).pretty();
>
```

an example of my database:

```
db.Subject.insert(
{
"_id":ObjectId(),
"subject": {
        "subCode":"CSCI114",
        "subTitle":"Procedural Programming",
        "credit":3,
        "type":"Core",
        "assessments": [
                { "assessNum": 1,
                  "weight":5,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 1 - Basic Concepts: Sequential Designs" },
                { "assignNum": 2,
                  "weight":5,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 2 - Control structures: Selection Designs" },
                { "assessNum": 3,
                  "weight":5,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 3 - Repetition Designs and Functions I" },
                { "assessNum": 4,
                  "weight":15,
                  "assessType":"Test/Quiz",
                  "description":"Closed-book Class Test" },
                { "assessNum": 5,
                  "weight": 10,
                  "assessType":"Test/Quiz",
                  "description":"Laboratory Test" },
                { "assessNum": 6,
                  "weight": 10,
                  "assessType":"Test/Quiz",
                  "description": "Closed-book Class Test" },
                { "assessNum": 7,
                  "weight":50,
                  "assessType":"Examination",
                  "description": "Closed-book Final Examination" }
            ],
        "book": [
                { "ISBN":"13:978-1-133-52635-3",
                  "bookType":"reference",
                  "bookTitle":"C++ Programming - Program design including data structure",
                  "edition":6,
                  "yearPub":2013,
                  "publisher":"CENGAGE Learning",
                  "author": [ "Malik D S" ] },
                { "ISBN":"13:978-0-273-75983-6",
                  "bookType":"reference",
                    "bookTitle":"Starting Out With C++: From Control Structures through Objects",
                  "edition":7,
                  "yearPub":2012,
                  "publisher":"Addison-Wesley",
                  "author": [ "Tony Gaddis" ] },

            ]
        }
}
)
db.Subject.insert(
{
"_id":ObjectId(),
"subject": {
        "subCode":"CSCI124",
        "subTitle":"Applied Programming",
        "credit":3,
        "type":"Core",
        "prerequisite": ["csci114"],
        "assessments": [
                { "assessNum": 1,
                  "weight":12,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 1 - Application on binary file processing" },
                { "assignNum": 2,
                  "weight":12,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 2 - Application on pointers" },
                { "assessNum": 3,
                  "weight":12,
                  "assessType":"Assignment",
                  "description":"Assignment 3 - Application on classes and objects and dynamic data structures" },
                { "assessNum": 4,
                  "weight":14,
                  "assessType":"Laboratory",
                  "description":"Laboraory/Implementation Tasks" },
                { "assessNum": 5,
                  "weight": 50,
                  "assessType":"Examination",
                  "description":"Closed-book Final Examination" }
            ],
        "book": [
                { "ISBN":"10:1-4390-4023-0",
                  "bookType":"textbook",
                  "bookTitle":"Data Structures Using C++",
                  "edition":2,
                  "yearPub":2010,
                  "publisher":"CENGAGE Learning",
                  "author": [ "Malik D S" ] },
                { "ISBN":"13:978-1-133-52635-3",
                  "bookType":"reference",
                    "bookTitle":"C++ Programming - Program design including data structure",
                  "edition":6,
                  "yearPub":2013,
                  "publisher":"CENGAGE Learning",
                  "author": [ "Malik D S" ] },
                { "ISBN":"13:978-0-273-75983-6",
                  "bookType":"reference",
                    "bookTitle":"Starting Out With C++: From Control Structures through Objects",
                  "edition":7,
                  "yearPub":2012,
                  "publisher":"Addison-Wesley",
                  "author": [ "Tony Gaddis" ] }
            ]
        }
}
)
```

Please help me because I really don't understand why is it not working

Comment: subject is an object not array so no need to $unwind : since it is used to destruct an array
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: I have tried $unwind on book but it does not work as well

Comment: It should be working, to try run query without match and see what path you are getting to filter books

Comment: it works without the $match, does this mean they couldn't find a match?

Comment: yes cause you removed yearPub field in first project stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are removing yearPub field in the first stage and later comparing it in match stage

```
db.Subject.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "books": "$subject.book"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$books"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "books.yearPub": 2012
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "books.ISBN": 1,
      "books.bookTitle": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Order of your aggregation stages is not correct. Move the `$project` at last.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$subject.book"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "subject.book.yearPub": 2012
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "subject.book.ISBN": 1,
      "subject.book.bookTitle": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Here is working example.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yd6JzIi2zXj)